# How to extract list of columns from a csv file and create a new file with 2 new columns of calculated values

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file from which I want to extract a list of columns. After doing that I would like to create a new csv file with the columns extracted from the previous one and with two new columns Function1 and Function2 that consist in the sum of the points for each client  from times 0.001 s to  0.005 and from 0.006 to 0.01. So I have two problems.

This is the first .csv file   except for time column in the others there are some point assigned to the subjects of the columns (just to clarify)

```
time  |client1_points| client2_points| client3_points| server1_points|server2_points
0.001     
0.002
0.003
0.004
0.005
0.006
0.007
0.008
0.009
0.01
```

So, to filter only the columns that I want I thought about a script in this way

```
import math
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt



    df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=',')
    print(df.columns)  # check that the  columns are parsed correctly 
    selected_columns = [col for col in df.columns if ["time, client"] in col]
    df_filtered = df[selected_columns]
    df_filtered.to_csv('new_testfile.csv')
```

unfortunately I don't know why this doesn't work because I'm not able to make the list ["time, client"] working.

The next problem is that I want to create two function "Average1" and "Average2":

1. Function1 must calculate the sum of (client1_point+client2_points+client3_points) from time 0.001 to 0.005
2. Function2 must calculate the sum of (client1_point+client2_points+client3_points) from time 0.006 to 0.01

The values calculated of this two functions must be integrated directly in the new .csv that was created.

Some ideas to solve the problems?

I would like to obtain the resulting .csv sheet with this columns

```
time  |client1_points| client2_points| client3_points| Func1| Func2 

0.001     1                  2                1         4       0
0.002     1                  1                2         4       0 
0.003     2                  3                9         14      0
0.004     2                  5                4         11      0 
0.005     4                  9                8         21      0
0.006     8                  1                0          0      9  
0.007     4                  1                0          0      5
0.008     7                  0                0          0      7
0.009     1                  0                9          0      10
0.01      2                  1                0          0      3
```

Thanks a lot to everyone.

Comment: It would be useful to include in question an example of desired output, given 10 or so lines or example data.

Comment: 1) There is no such thing as a CSV sheet. CSV is a text file format. 2) Provide examples of the files that have the points data.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can use this code to keep only the desired columns:

```
columns = ['time'] + [el for el in df.columns if 'client' in el]
df = df[columns]
```

Then you have to perform two separate calculations (you can also do it in one step but maybe it is slower) to find the sums:

```
df.loc[df['time'] <= 0.005, 'Func1'] = df['client1_points'] + df['client2_points'] + df['client3_points'] 
df.loc[df['time'] > 0.005, 'Func2'] = df['client1_points'] + df['client2_points'] + df['client3_points']
```